# Check if Value exist in another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
if(formS.getRange("B2").getValue()   )// check if value exist in another sheet
 { 

 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("duplicate record");
 return
}
```

I want to check if submitted values on the form exist on another sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by iterating the values of the other sheet. And then check using `includes` if any row contain the certain value. See the code below.

#### Code:

```
function checkValue() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = sheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var formD = sheet.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  var valueToSearch = formS.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var formDValues = formD.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Filter the other sheet's data where a row contains the valueToSearch
  // If it has at least 1 element, then it is duplicate
  if(formDValues.filter(row => row.includes(valueToSearch)).length) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("duplicate record");
    return
  }
}
```

#### Sheet1:

[image: sheet1]

#### Sheet2:

[image: sheet2]

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: I set the background color to 'red' if there is duplicate record. What if the row has been fixed and no longer a "duplicate", how do you set it back to  remove the background color and default it to white?